# How to set vertical space between two figures in subcaption environment?

Tags: spacing, subcaption, vertical, subfig

I've tried with different commands like: `\vspace*{10mm}` `\vfill` but they do not work!

This is the main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_ang_loop_per.eps}
         \caption{Componenti $p(t)$, $q(t)$ e $r(t)$ della velocità angolare.}
         \label{fig:p,q,r_loop_perf}
     \end{subfigure}
     \vfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_trasl_loop_per.eps}
         \caption{Componenti $u(t)$, $v(t)$, $w(t)$ della velocità del baricentro.}
         \label{fig:u,v,w_loop_perf}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Storie temporali delle componenti di velocità angolare e traslazionale  assegnate per la manovra di \textit{looping perfetto}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: you say you want to set space -- why not code the space requirement as `\end{subfigure}\\[3in]`  -- see the answer below

Comment: I usually add \vskip\floatsep between rows of subfigures (the normal distance between floats).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_ang_loop_per.eps}
            \caption{Componenti $p(t)$, $q(t)$ e $r(t)$ della velocità angolare.}
            \label{fig:p,q,r_loop_perf}
        \end{subfigure}\\[3in]
        
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_trasl_loop_per.eps}
            \caption{Componenti $u(t)$, $v(t)$, $w(t)$ della velocità del baricentro.}
            \label{fig:u,v,w_loop_perf}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Storie temporali delle componenti di velocità angolare e traslazionale  assegnate per la manovra di \textit{looping perfetto}}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for both your `subfigure`s to be at the `b`ottom.

The easiest solution might be to add the `\vspace` to the first `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
         \centering
         (\texttt{vel\_ang\_loop\_per.eps} goes here)
         \caption{Componenti $p(t)$, $q(t)$ e $r(t)$ della velocità angolare.}
         \label{fig:p,q,r_loop_perf}
         \vspace{1in}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
         \centering
         (\texttt{vel\_trasl\_loop\_per.eps} goes here)
         \caption{Componenti $u(t)$, $v(t)$, $w(t)$ della velocità del baricentro.}
         \label{fig:u,v,w_loop_perf}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Storie temporali delle componenti di velocità angolare e traslazionale  assegnate per la manovra di \textit{looping perfetto}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```