# How can I place two sub figures under each other vertically?

Tags: subfig

since I already saw that this question has already been asked here, I tried the suggested solutions but the problem still exists.
I have two sub figures that are wide and I would like to place them under each other.
Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
{
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image1}
    \caption{fig1}
    \label{fig2}\par\vfill
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.5\textwidth}
     \vspace*{\fill}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image2}
    \caption{fig2}
    \label{fig:fig2}
\end{subfigure}%
    \caption{fig2}}
    \label{fig:fig2}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I tried \newline but did not work.
Here is what I get on the pdf:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzXqD.png
I would be thankful for any solution..
Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: Insert blank line between subfigures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my other answer -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590492/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_ang_loop_per.eps}
            \caption{Componenti $p(t)$, $q(t)$ e $r(t)$ della velocità angolare.}
            \label{fig:p,q,r_loop_perf}
        \end{subfigure}\\[3in]%<--------------------vary the separation
        
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_trasl_loop_per.eps}
            \caption{Componenti $u(t)$, $v(t)$, $w(t)$ della velocità del baricentro.}
            \label{fig:u,v,w_loop_perf}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Storie temporali delle componenti di velocità angolare e traslazionale  assegnate per la manovra di \textit{looping perfetto}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `subfigure` environment you need `subcaption`. For `\includegraphics` you need `graphicx`. For the `ngerman` option you need `babel`.

Next, `\vspace*{\fill}` and `\vfill` inside `subfigure` do nothing at all. Also, `subfigure` doesn't know what to do with the `[h]` option: it accepts `[t]`, `[b]` or `[c]` (the last one being the default) to specify the vertical appearance of the built box; in this case you need `[c]` (hence you can omit it).

Using `scale=0.5` is wrong: you most likely want to scale the image to the size given for `subfigure`. With `scale` you have no idea about the final size of the image, so `width=\linewidth` is preferable, because TeX will use the size reserved for `subfigure`.

You also need to fix the labels.

If you need some vertical space between the image, add it. The trick is to have a blank line between the `subfigure` environments (with a `\vspace` instruction in between).

```
\documentclass[
  ngerman,
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  oneside,
  listof=totoc,
  plainfootsepline,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{fig1}
  \label{subfig:fig1}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{3ex}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{fig2}
  \label{subfig:fig2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{fig2}
\label{fig:fig}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* need `scale`, you can use `\subcaptionbox` that doesn't need a width to begin with.

```
\documentclass[
  ngerman,
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  oneside,
  listof=totoc,
  plainfootsepline,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\subcaptionbox{fig1\label{subfig:fig1}}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}%
}

\vspace{3ex}

\subcaptionbox{fig2\label{subfig:fig2}}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}%
}

\caption{fig2}
\label{fig:fig}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `plainfootsepline` option only makes sense if you load `scrlayer-scrpage`.